# How to remove custom listeners?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have many `ListActivity` classes in my app that act pretty much the same : list with a property (`TextView`) on the left and a value (`Button`) on the right. When I press the button I want to do something like create a dialog. Because of the repetability, I decided to create a general custom `ArrayAdapter` like this :

```
public class GeneralTvBtnAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SettingsProperty> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<SettingsProperty> mProps;
private int mLayout;
private ButtonListener mListener;

public GeneralTvBtnAdapter(Context context, int tv_btn_layout, ArrayList<SettingsProperty> objects, ButtonListener listener) {
    super(context, tv_btn_layout, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mProps = objects;
    mLayout = tv_btn_layout;
    mListener = listener;
}

public void updateValue (int position, String newValue) {
    mProps.get(position).setValue(newValue);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView mName;
    Button mValue;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mLayout, null);
        holder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prop);
        holder.mValue = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mName.setText(mProps.get(position).getName());
    holder.mValue.setText(mProps.get(position).getValue());

    holder.mValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onButtonClicked(position);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public interface ButtonListener {
    void onButtonClicked (int position);
}
}
```

I want to know how can I remove the ButtonListeners listeners after the calling activity is destroyed.

P.S :**SettingsProperty** is a **POJO** with String name and `String` value and the **tv_btn_layout** is a layout with a `TextView` and a `Button` as described above.

Comment: AFAIK, Android will automatically remove all listeners when the activity gets destroyed.

Comment: I want to write clean code, that's all. Does anyone know how to monitor the variables in memory at a certain point in the execution of a program?

Answer (score 1):

if your intent is to *remove* your custom listener, you have to reset it to null. You can create a setter

```
public void setButtonListener (final ButtonListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

and call if from the outside with `null`. Just to be sure, before accessing `mListener`, check for `null` values

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is not to call listener method if activity is destroyed then override your onfinish() of Activity and initialize the boolean flag.

```
private boolean IsActivityAlive;

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
    IsActivityAlive=true;
     super.onDestroy();
    }
```

And inside your interface method just check for boolean flag if it is false do the action required else ignore

```
   void onButtonClicked (int position){
   if(!IsActivityAlive){

      //Do remaining task }

    }
```